# Ext 4.1.1: Label inside a surrounding div

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

Hy there,

how can i create an Ext.form.Label that is always surrounded by a div without losing all the functionality of the label (setText, ...)?
I've already played a little with autoEl, rendertTpl and manually creating the div and moving the label into it in afterrender but nothing really worked out too well.

I'd really appreciate some help on this!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a div in label text hiding a labelSeparator:

```
    {
        xtype: 'textarea',
        anchor: '100%',
        rows: 8,
        padding: '5 5 20 5',
        fieldLabel: '<div style="border: #999 solid 1px; padding: 5px;">Label text:</div>',
        labelSeparator: ''
    }
```

[Result screenshot](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/6795/20130128-wqcw-7kb.jpg)

Or use html property of Ext.form.Label.